# How to align the functionality of SUBSTITUTE() to the that of Vim's :substitute command for a given regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to deconstruct why this does not work in my (g)Vim console:

```
:echo substitute("2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm","\([0-9]\+\)\(||.*\)$","\1","g")
```

... but when the cursor is on the line with the text `2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm`, the analogous command `.s/\([0-9]\+\)\(||.*\)$/\1/g` returns what I expect! (that is, it replaces the line with the text `2321`)

---

I've narrowed it down to the following discrepancy, and would like to know how to get around it. I expect the command below to return `||aaaa|vvvv||mmmmm`:

```
:echo substitute("2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm","\([0-9]\)","","g")
```

Instead, it returns the unchanged version of the input `2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm`, which means the regex `\([0-9]\)` did not find a match. Removing the parenthesis, the command below **does** work:

```
:echo substitute("2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm","[0-9]","","g")
```

It appears as if the `SUBSTITUTE()` function has severely limited regex capabilty when compared to the `:substitute` command. However, the documentation 
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute%28%29 does not mention this. Is there a workaround, or did I miss something that is mentioned elsewhere?

---

(I'm running gVim on XP)

As an aside: *Does the question as it is currently formulated add or take away from its clarity/usefulness?* I could have also used the simpler but less informative title of 'Vim substitute question', in line with many other users of this forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use single quotes or escape backslashes

```
:echo substitute("2321||aaaa|vvvv|334|mmmmm",'\([0-9]\+\)\(||.*\)$','\1','g')
```

See `:help expr-quote` and `:help literal-string`.